# h:inputText -Field is visible?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, jsf-2

i am developing a jsf web application with netbeans.

```
    <fieldset>
        <div>
           <h:inputText id="firstname" value="#{loginCtrl.customer.name}" label="Name">
                  <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
           </h:inputText>
        <div>
...
```

I wrote that code but when I deploy it to the apache tomcat server, there is no field shown? Why? h:input has no visibility element?

greetings and thx in advance

PS.: my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/register.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the request URL as you see in browser's address bar matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as specified in `web.xml`. You can verify this by rightclicking the page in browser and viewing the generated HTML source. If the `<h:inputText>` is still there, then it means that the `FacesServlet` isn't been invoked at all.

If you open the page by `/page.xhtml`, then the `FacesServlet` is apparently not mapped on `*.xhtml`, but on `*.jsf` or something else. You'd need to change the URL in browser's address bar accordingly to match exactly the specified URL pattern, or to fix the mapping accordingly.

Comment: ok I did all the renaming and my output has changed: I do not get the site, but I get a print of the code in the browser window? Why?

Comment: You seem to have changed the extension of the actual view file from `.xhtml` to `.jsf`. This is not right. You need to keep the extension of the actual view file .xhtml`. Change the `<url-pattern>` value of `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml`. Change the `<welcome-file>` to `register.xhtml`. This way you do not need to fiddle with virtual URLs like `/faces` or `.jsf` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`h:input has no visibility element?`

Yes, the `h:inputText` element have `rendered` attribute:

```
<h:inputText id="firstname" rendered="true" value="#{loginCtrl.customer.name}" 
    label="Name">
      <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8"/>
</h:inputText>
```

But the defalut is true so the preblem is not with that...

Comment: thx for your answer!!! Yes the problem is not with that(i tried it^^)... Is there probably a tag before the h:inputText Element?

Comment: @user1248720 Try to put an `HTML input` tag and see if you see him...
<input type="text" id="firstname" value="test" />